# How to get content within a A HREF tag using wildcard (PHP)

Tags: php, xpath, wildcard

Im trying to get content of a series of A HREF tags in PHP, eg:

```
<a href="/user/200890"></a>
<a href="/user/200891"></a>
<a href="/user/200892"></a>
```

I'm using this, but don't know how to get all tags using wildcard - I tried this, bu didn't work:

```
$anchorTags = $xPath->evaluate("//a[@href*=\"/user\"]");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `start-with` selector in your XPath query

```
$strhtml='
    <a href="/user/200890"></a>
    <a href="/user/200891"></a>
    <a href="/user/200892"></a>     
';


libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->loadHTML( $strhtml );
$errors=libxml_get_errors();
libxml_clear_errors();


$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$pttn='//a[ starts-with( @href, "/user/" ) ]';

$col=$xp->query( $pttn );
if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->getAttribute('href') . '<br>';
}
```

This outputs, as expected:

```
/user/200890
/user/200891
/user/200892
```